# How to update table from another table, with 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server database and want a way to update `MachinesSummary.ShareCount`.

Here are my two tables

**MachinesSummary**

```
ID Machine1 Machine2 ShareCount
-------------------------------
1  A        J        NULL
2  K        S        NULL
3  A        E        NULL
4  J        A        NULL
5  Y        U        NULL
6  S        W        NULL
7  G        A        NULL
8  W        S        NULL
```

The other table is **MachineDetails**

```
ProcessNo Machine
------------------
1         A
1         H
1         W
2         A
2         J
2         W
3         Y
3         K
4         J
4         A
```

I want to update `ShareCount` in the `MachineSummary` table with the count of processes that both `Machine1` and `Machine2` share.

For record *1* in the `MachineSummary` table, I want the number of processes both share in `MachineDetails` which is *1* in this case

While for record *4* the `ShareCount` is *2*

I tried this

```
UPDATE M
SET ShareCount = COUNT(DISTINCT X.ProcessNo)
FROM 
    (SELECT ProcessNo, ',' + STRING_AGG(Machine,',') + ',' Machines
     FROM MachineDetails
     GROUP BY ProcessNo) X 
INNER JOIN MachinesSummary M ON X.Machines LIKE '%'+ M.Machine1 + '%' 
                             AND X.Machines LIKE '%'+ M.Machine2 + '%'
```

But I wonder if there is an easier high performance way

The `MachineDetails` table has 250 million rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would use a `self-join` to get the number of combinations:

```
UPDATE M
    SET ShareCount = num_processes
FROM MachinesSummary M JOIN
     (SELECT md1.Machine as machine1, md2.Machine as machine2, COUNT(*) as num_processes
      FROM MachineDetails md1 JOIN
           MachinesDetails md2
           ON md1.processno = md2.processno
      GROUP BY md1.Machine, md2.Machine
     ) md
     ON md.Machine1 = M.machine1 AND md.Machine2 = M.machine2;
```

Comment: Getthing this error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."

Comment: Its just missing the join condition... add it in and you'll be good.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an updatable CTE here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Machine, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM MachineDetails
    GROUP BY Machine
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT ShareCount, COALESCE(t1.cnt, 0) AS m1_cnt, COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS m2_cnt
    FROM MachineSummary ms
    LEFT JOIN cte t1 ON t1.Machine1 = ms.Machine
    LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t2.Machine2 = ms.Machine
)

UPDATE cte2
SET ShareCount = m1_cnt + m2_cnt;
```

The logic of the first CTE involving the `MachineDetails` table is to get the counts for every machine.  The second CTE joins this counts CTE to the `MachineSummary` table twice, once for each of machine 1 and 2.  Then, we update this second CTE and assign the sum of counts.